# How do I disable the openSuSE Tumbleweed "Software Updates" toolbar item?

Tags: opensuse, software-updates

I'm looking for a way to shut it off/prevent it from automatically running in the GUI.  I've been able to flip it to monthly which helps since it doesn't annoy me as much, but still I really want it off.

I do my updates manually with a zypper dup when I'm on high bandwidth connections.  Most of the time I'm on low bandwidth and the auto updater absolutely kills the network connections until it eventually gives up and fails out (after around 15 minutes), then I can use my computer again.

Answer (score 2):

When installing Tumbleweed you can choose automatic transactional updates, otherwise by default Tumbleweed doesn't update automatically, however it may automatically check what updates are available.  If you want to disable the automatic checking, your answer may be found in [opensuse System Updates](https://en.opensuse.org/System_Updates), eg. for kde:

```
sudo zypper remove plasma5-pk-updates
sudo zypper addlock plasma5-pk-updates
```

Answer (score 1):

In KDE;

right click to 'Unlock Widgets' then 'Configure System Tray' & uncheck option to disable software updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is desktop-dependant, and the poster has not specified what desktop this answer pertains to. It does not seem to work on XFCE.

Comment: doesn't work on tumbleweed kde either, probably cuz out of date